# C novice: why swprintf fail for me?

Tags: c, winapi

Please help! I know nothing about C but I have to make a tiny addition to C code.

I'm getting an error number (int)  from GetLastError and showing it to a form. Instead, I need to get the actual error string.

I added a call for FormatMessage. The call itself works fine, but the string doesn't print (crashes the program). What am I doing wrong?

```
wchar_t *textbuf;

if(textbuf==NULL)
        {
            textbuf=(wchar_t *)malloc(4096);
            memset(textbuf,0,4096);
        }

wchar_t *lpMsgBuf;
            FormatMessage(
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, rc, // rc is an int, returned from another function, the result of GetLastError()
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
                (LPWSTR)lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
swprintf(textbuf, L"%s%s%s\n", textbuf, L"\t\t\t", lpMsgBuf);
```

Comment: Regarding the edit; `wchar_t *textbuf;` will not set `textbuf` to `NULL`. Use `wchar_t *textbuf = NULL;`

Comment: Thanks. I did. Still failing at the same point :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing `lpMsgBuf` to `FormatMessage()` correctly, and you are mismanaging your `textbuf` buffer.

The [`FormatMessage()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) says:

> FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
>   0x00000100
>
> The function allocates a buffer large enough to hold the formatted message, and places a pointer to the allocated buffer at the address specified by lpBuffer. **The lpBuffer parameter is a pointer to an LPTSTR; you must cast the pointer to an LPTSTR (for example, `(LPTSTR)&lpBuffer`). The nSize parameter specifies the minimum number of TCHARs to allocate for an output message buffer**. The caller should use the `LocalFree` function to free the buffer when it is no longer needed.

Since you are not initializing `lpMsgBuf` to NULL, and not passing the **address of** `lpMsgBuf` to `FormatMessage()` so it can assign the allocated memory address to `lpMsgBuf`, you end up passing a garbage memory address to `swprintf()` as the final input parameter.

As for `textbuf`, you are not initializing it to NULL, so you end up skipping the call to `malloc()`, and thus you pass garbage addresses to `swprintf()` for both its output buffer and its first input parameter.  Which, you cannot use the same buffer for input and output anyway, that is undefined behavior.

Try this instead:

```
wchar_t *textbuf = (wchar_t *) malloc(4096);
memset(textbuf, 0, 4096 * sizeof(wchar_t));

wchar_t *lpMsgBuf = NULL;
FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL, rc, // rc is an int, returned from another function, the result of GetLastError()
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
    (LPWSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
swprintf(textbuf, L"\t\t\t%s\n", lpMsgBuf);
LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

// use textbuf as needed...
free(textbuf);
```

Comment: Thank you - this is what @IInspectable wrote above and this solved the problem. The only difference is that I didn't specify 256 in the size, I used 0, and this worked... should that be OK?

Comment: Use whatever size you actually need.  256 was just an example.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you again.

Comment: When using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` flag, the *nSize* parameter doesn't specify the size of the output buffer. Instead, it specifies the minimum number of characters to allocate for the output buffer. Using anything other than `0` in this case is hardly ever useful.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't assign any memory to `textbuf`. So consider using an aribtrary size value such as `wchar_t textbuf[50]` or dynamic memory allocation with `malloc`.

Also, in the last line, you're using `textbuf` as the third argument. That makes no sense since it is empty (or has garbage) and will <del>always</del> *probably* overcome the buffer size.

Comment: The final assessment is not necessarily correct. The *%s* specifier outputs a C-style string, that is delimited by a *NUL* character (not the buffer's size). The buffer could be large enough to hold a copy of itself as a C-style string as well as additional content. There is another mistake, though, as pointed out in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx): *"If copying occurs between strings that overlap, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @IInspectable Right, thanks. However it seems to be an error in this case!

Comment: Your fix didn't make the statement any better. Accessing invalid/uninitialized memory is *undefined behavior*. There's no merit in guessing at its outcome, since **anything** can happen.

Comment: I truly appologize but I made a mistake. The code is edited from the original which is much longer, and textBuff is indeed initialized, and may also contain a value. I added the initialization code to the original post. Again, I do not know C, I forgot that this would be important.
The code still breaks...

Comment: @IInspectable Not guessing. I'm saying that the string to be copied will be probably bigger than what `textbuf` can store.

Comment: @user884248 you did not address the last statement. You cannot use `textbuf` as your third argument, as the behavior is undefined.

Comment: You are failing to see the important detail here: The edit to the question didn't change much. It's still undefined behavior (as pointed out in my first comment). When using *textbuf* both as the source and the target, then clearly those buffers overlap.

Comment: @IInspectable - I see your point, but the original code was exactly identical to this, except the third argument was an int (rc), and the format string was %s%s%d. And that worked perfectly.

Comment: @user884248: *Undefined behavior* is allowed to exhibit **any** observable behavior, including appearing to *"work like a charm"*. It's still a bug, and it needs to be fixed. You cannot append text like that.

Answer (score 2):

When calling [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) with the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` flag, the *lpBuffer* parameter must be a pointer to a pointer:

```
wchar_t *lpMsgBuf = NULL;
FormatMessageW( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL,
                rc, // rc is an int, returned from another function, the result of
                    // GetLastError()
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
                (LPWSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

// Do something with lpMsgBuf

// Cleanup system allocated memory
LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
// Since LocalFree is missing from the Windows 10 SDK you'll need to call HeapFree
// on Windows 10 and above:
HeapFree( GetProcessHeap(), lpMsgBuf );
```

You still need to address another bug. Passing a buffer both as an input as well as an output to [swprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) is illegal:

> If copying occurs between strings that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, and thank you again! This solved the problem. You don't know what a huge help this is. I'll work on fixing the other problem as well.